# what is a good way to learn new framework / language?

Tags: self-learning, programming, resource-request, best-practice, struggling-students

I have been learning rust since 2021. I followed different courses from YouTube and others. Then I shifted towards books to learn rust and right now after two years I am doing same thing and learning rust from documents from the webs.

My main point to learn rust is that when I am learning form YouTube playlist of Indian YouTuber basically the playlist is well-designed, but there are some main concepts missing, so I shifted books to learn advance topics of rust. After reading half of different books I think I know rust so decide to create some projects. After creating all this stuff, I realized I am stuck again in some topics and some concepts are missing, or I don't know them.

After that right now after 2 year I am learning rust again.

My main question is what is the best way to learn a new framework / language, and how to avoid the loop where I am stuck.

Comment: If there was a single best way, everyone would just do that. Instead of looking for a silver bullet that doesn't exist, perhaps describe what you're stuck on, specifically, and the goals you want to achieve.

Comment: @ggorlen : stuck in concepts which i don't know! whenever i look for some code; lots of time there are some concepts which i don't know. and 2nd is i forget lots of concepts.

Comment: Thanks. What are some of those concepts you're stuck on?

Comment: @ggorlen: oop and also some basic stuff like i know how to code but not on rust standard wise

Comment: Rust is not Object-Oriented, in the way most people define Object-Oriented. However, most people's definition does not meet that of Alen Key's original usage. Rust has modules for encapsulation, it has structures, it has interfaces (`traits`), etc.

Comment: I fixed some grammar to make the question more readable, and less ambiguous. Please proofread, and correct, if I changed any meaning. However, It is hard to see what your goals are, or to see what you are stuck on. Edit the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Before one can recommend the best way, one must be sure how to measure the goodness of learning methods. After that there might be a criterion to choose the best one.

Comment: Tell us your experience, age, and goals. Update the question to tell us these, and to address other comments.

Answer (score -1):

If you are self-taught, understanding the concepts may require a hard sciences course before studying the framework or programming language. Dedicated instructors or support should be available to facilitate learning. You usually learn by looking for examples and asking on forums. Some things are just too hard to work on or learn when you're not getting paid.

Comment: Computer science is not a science. Money is not a good motivator.